# How do I create a command like \title in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I am writing a document class for LaTeX and I want it to be generic. In this document class I redefine the `\maketitle` command to display a custom title page, and here I want to display some information, like the title, author, etc., but also some other informations. Here is how I display the title:

```
{\LARGE{\bf \@title}}\\
```

I'd like to create a new command that works similarly to `\title` or `\author`, how can I do that?

Comment: This might be more fit for the LaTeX SE.

Comment: @Someone funny enough this question was asked  3 weeks before the LaTeX SE was first proposed and 2 and a half months before the public beta: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3175/when-was-the-tex-latex-site-at-stack-exchange-founded

Comment: That was a definite oof moment for me, then.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you look at `latex.ltx` you can see that `\title` is defined as follows:

```
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}}
\def\@title{\@latex@error{No \noexpand\title given}\@ehc}
```

Those are low-level TeX commands. `\title` is a command that redefines `\@title` to expand to the argument given to `\title`. In more modern LaTeX commands your own definition could look like this:

```
\newcommand\foo[1]{\renewcommand\@foo{#1}}
\newcommand\@foo{\@latex@error{No \noexpand\foo given}\@ehc}
```

It's better to use `\PackageError` or `\ClassError` to show the error message. Or, if you want `\foo` to be optional and be empty by default:

```
\newcommand\foo[1]{\renewcommand\@foo{#1}}
\newcommand\@foo{}
```

If this is not inside a package, you'll have to put it between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` because of the `@` signs.

Comment: Can you explain what each part of the code is doing? For instance, why are there two lines of declarations, why there is ```\newcommand\foo[1]{}``` which contains ```\renewcommand\@foo{#1}``` and so on? Also, why does it need to be between ```\makeatletter``` and ```\makeatother```? What are these things and what do they do?
Sorry, I'm just trying to understand this better.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. I'll leave my explanation here for posterity. Look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do for an explanation of ```\makeatletter``` and ```\makeatother```. What we are doing is by default defining ```\@foo``` to throw an error message, if it is not overridden by a declaration of ```\foo```. ```\foo``` is then renewing the ```\@foo``` command to whatever argument we give it (by saying ```\foo{blah blah}``` etc) And then in ```\@maketitle```, we can use ```\@foo``` like we use ```\@title```, ```\@date```, etc.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a sample command I used in my `thesis.cls` class. It defines a new command `\university` that works as the `\title` or `\author` commands with a default value equals to "no university". If I don't use the `\university` command in my preamble the default value will be used instead.

```
\def\@university{no university}
\newcommand{\university}[1]{
  \def\@university{#1}
}
```

Then, in the `\maketitle` command you can have something like:

```
\newcommand{\maketitle}{
  {\LARGE{\bf \@title}}\\
  {\small{\@university}}\\
}
```